# Ruby input image file

Tags: ruby, image, user-input

I am using Ruby to write a codec to compress an image. Right now I am using a hardcoded image file, but I would like to retrieve an image file from the user.

What would be the proper syntax of gathering this information?

Here is what I currently have:

```
# Set the path for the input image
path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../Images/my_image.png"
image = ImageList.new(path)
```

Then I am manipulating the image using RMagick, but that's irrelevant. What is the proper way to allowing the user to give me an image from his current path in the console?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean from the command line? Something like `your_script pancakes.png`?

Comment: Yes, something like this would be nice. Or even have the script ask the user for a file. Whatever is more efficient and easier.

Comment: See the `ARGV` answers below if you just want to pull something off the command line, interactively asking for it would be more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call your script from the commandline like this: 
`$ myscript.rb path_to_file.jpg`

and in your script, you can access the string with `ARGV`, e.g.

```
ARGV.each do |argument|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A common way would be to just use plain old [ARGV](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_and_Its_World_ARGV.html) (note that unlike other languages this does NOT include the program name). If you have mandatory arguments you can do something like:

```
unless ARGV.size > 0
    puts "Usage: $0 file_name [second_file]
end
```

You also could use one of the various option parsers like [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html) or [Trollop](http://trollop.rubyforge.org/) if you want something like

```
script_name --input input_file --output output_file
```